# Django user model custom fields names

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

How to rename fields of the user model?

I want to rename the fields

`first_name to firstName, last_name to lastName` with AbstractUser

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address',unique=True)
    firstName = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=150)
    lastName = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=150)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'username',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
    ]
```

The above code works, but it does not rename the fields what it does is add the fields `firstName and lastName`

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: what is the reasoning behind rename, you really do not want to have camelCase attribute names in python, rather use db_column if database is preexisting

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the `db_column` parameter, so you can hopefully override AbstractUser's default fields.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address',unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", db_column="firstName", max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", db_column="lastName", max_length=150)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'username',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
    ]
```

With reference to the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column

Answer (score -1):

You can simply override the respective field in the inherited class and create a new field with a new name instead if you really don't want to use any alias name or `db_column` as Barney Szabolcs mentioned.

Therefore, we can override `first_name` and `last_name` with `' '` to avoid any exception error as they've been used in other areas — admin `field_sets`, `get_full_name` method, etc. Or you can also override them as well.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = ' '
    last_name = ' '
    firstName = models.CharField('First name', max_length=150)
    lastName = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=150)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'username',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
    ]
```

Note that you must add the following line in the `settings.py`:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<respective-app-name>.User'
```

Moreover, to ensure that you can check the created migration file content.